# Coerce string of timestamp OR interval to timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field that specifies a timestamp in the future, an expiry for a record. I'd like to be able to accept a string timestamp or an interval representing the time from now. Is there some simple way to attempt to cast a string to an interval, if it succeeds then add it to `now()` otherwise cast it to a timestamp (with time zone)?

Before it gets asked, yes I'm sure I could do it with a stored proc, I'm curious about if I could use some type of `COALESCE` style magick. If the answer is stored proc then so be it, I can write that one.

---

Edit: Here is my implementation as a stored proc.

```
create or replace function
  timestamptz_in_or_at(input text) 
  returns timestamptz
  as $$
  begin
    begin
      return now() + input::interval;
    exception when others then
      return input::timestamptz;
    end;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: The problem with anything like this is error handling. If you just stick a cast into there and the string isn't made right, you'll get a SQL error. If you want to see if you can cast it without breaking the current transaction etc, then you can either use savepoints in SQL or write a plpgsql function with error handling. Either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only chance is validating the interval string with regex, because CAST throws an error on invalid strings and make_interval hasn't got a signature for string input.

The interval input format is [known](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT). You can write a regex for the precision you want in postgres_verbose or the ISO format.

For example:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN your_text_column ~* '^(\d+ (minute|minutes|second|seconds)\ *)+$'
  THEN now() + your_text_column::interval
  ELSE your_text_column::timestamptz END 
FROM test;
```

In this case you must read the interval/timestamp string from a table's text type column. On the other hand, when your input string is coming from user input, the query will become more complex. You have to deal with the planner that tries to optimize constant values, even in the CASE's false branches. To prevent this, you must introduce a volatile function into one of the expressions:

```
SELECT
  CAST(
    CASE WHEN ? ~* '^(\d+ (minute|minutes|second|seconds)\ *)+$'
    THEN CAST(now() + CAST((? || repeat('',(random()*0)::integer)) AS interval) AS text)
    ELSE ? END 
  AS timestamptz);
```

First, the CASE's branches must return the same type. Interval and timestamp are not compatible, but `text` is good. Second, in either case, one of the CASTs will fail, except if you can defer the evaluation to the runtime phase.

In the interval branch, `|| repeat('',(random()*0)::integer` add nothing to the string, but introduce volatility and stop the planner evaluating a possibly wrong interval text.

The outer CAST defer the evaluation of the CASE's ELSE branch to runtime where it is certain, that the string not contains an interval.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I think you've confirmed that in all practical purposes what I've hoped for isn't possible. I'm adding my stored proc as an edit and I think it shows how much simpler that overall. Thanks again!

Comment: I agree, the stored procedure is the best way to accomplish this.